# Какую методику применить для анализа изменяемого текста (на Python)?

Tags: python, анализатор

Задача функции - **сравнить входной текст с уже имеющимся и, если он изменился, сигнализировать об этом**. Такая задача возникла при написании бота, который оповещает о новости на определенной странице сайта. Дело в том, что текст на (чужом) сайте обновляется ручным способом, и поэтому часто бывает, что текст обновился, но автор решил исправить пару слов, ошибки в написании и проч. Раньше я *тупо* сравнивал 2 текста, одинаковы ли они или нет, но теперь хочу сделать более-менее цивилизованно, чтобы триггер не срабатывал, если в новом тексте просто добавилась какая-нибудь запятая. Пока что я делаю это таким способом:

```
def findMessageOverlap(new_message, old_message):
    overlap_count = 0
    for word in new_message.strip(' '):
        if word in old_message:
            overlap_count += 1
    overlap_percentage = (100 * overlap_count) / len(old_message.strip(' '))
    # if overlap percentage is less than 50%, there is new message on the site
    if overlap_percentage < 50:
        return overlap_percentage
```

Я обращаю разницу во встречающихся словах нового текста в проценты, и если текст отличается больше чем на 50% от старого, то сигнализирую об этом. **Как вы, опытные разработчики, решили бы такую задачу?** Потому что я лишь начинающий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Интересная задача) По ней достаточно много обсуждений в теории алгоритмов.
Как примеры решений:

**[Алгоритм Шинглов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)**

Самый распространненный подход под Вашу задачу ( его как раз используют для выявления плагиатов ).

[реализации python](http://www.codeisart.ru/blog/python-shingles-algorithm/)

[реализация python part2](https://habrahabr.ru/post/65944/)

**[Расстояние Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0)**

Это минимальное количество операций для перехода из одной строки в другую.

[реализация python](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0#Python)

**библиотеки в помощь:**

1. [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html)

в частности посмотрите в сторону [SequenceMatcher](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher). Этот класс поможет избавиться от заранее заданных "шумов" ( запятые, табуляции, ненужные части речи )

2. [python-Levenshtein](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein)

библиотека реализации алгоритма поиска Расстояния Левенштейна

PS: прошу прощения за то, что не привел четкого решения под Вашу задачу.
Но она достаточно обстрактна что бы просто вставить кусок кода, который Вас выручит. Но в указанных мною ссылках, Вы вполне найдете составные блоки для ее решения.

Comment: Спасибо за полезные ссылки, о которых я не знал. Я как раз спрашивал про подход, реализация в коде - это уже вторично :)